# In Next.js: How to redirect all empty routes to a route of my choosing

Tags: javascript, next.js

If I type in a dead endpoint in Next.js I get a 404 error. Instead, I want all unused routes to redirect to a default route and in this case, the landing page.

I have been researching this for over an hour and I don't believe this task warrants this amount of effort. It should be very easy.

I decided to ask.

Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create a custom 404 page which redirects.

```
//src/pages/404.js
    
import React, { useEffect } from 'react'
import Router from 'next/router'


export default function Custom404() {

  useEffect(() => {
    Router.push('/')
  },[])

  return null
}
```

Comment: my bad, u need to use useeffect to redirect on client side. updated codes.